# .NET CF 3.5, suspend and memory leaks

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, windows-ce

We have a WinForms application (sales mostly, uses wifi/mobile data for host connections) running on a handheld device (windows CE 6.0, CF framework 3.5, visual studio 2008).

Problem is that when our application is running and user suspends the device, i.e. it goes into sleep mode, then after it's woken up from suspend, our application's memory usage (physical, virtual seems fine) starts to raise constantly, until it will start getting out of memory errors.

When suspend isn't used, the application's memory usage is pretty much constant. We've added some extensive logging and memory usage is around 45%-48%, even after hours and hours of intensive usage of the application.

But as soon as the device is suspended while the application is still running, and woken up from suspend, the memory usage starts to grow. By small amounts, but still constantly. Like for example, after 30 minutes of usage, the memory raised from 45% (where it was after suspend) to 85%. And the application wasn't used any differently when testing it without suspend.

It's like the device wants to take another 45-48% of memory that it normally uses when application is run, after the suspend.

Now, i cannot do anything about the fact, that suspend is used when application is running. It's a feature that our users use constantly.

Is there anything i can do about this memory leak? Since without suspend, it never happens, i'm out of ideas, how to test it further to pinpoint the problem.

Should i explicitly call `GC.Collect`? or does this sound more like an OS level problem? or can there be something in our code that only results in memory leaks after suspend mode?

Comment: "_can there be something in our code that only results in memory leaks after suspend mode_" - noone knows except those who can see your code.

Comment: It was more of a general question about windows ce, c#, winforms and suspend. Like does suspend affect something specific by any chance. Like for example if my application were to be on SD card, then suspend would drop all handles and my application won't run after suspend. Something along those lines.